# A better way to compare the equality of two arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

## GOAL

Ensure that two string arrays are the same, and more specifically, are the same length and contain the same items.

## CODE

So, in my unit test I have the following code:

```
var sut = new PersonValid();
var expected = new string[] { "Id", "FirstName", "LastName" };

Assert.AreEqual(expected.Length, sut.DataFields.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(0, sut.DataFields.Where(df => !expected.Contains(df)).Count());
```

and it works, but it's really not that elegant. There's got to be a better way doesn't there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the sequence to be equal as well then:

You can use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`

```
var IsEqual = sut.DataFields.SequenceEqual(expected);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that break with multiple identical strings?

Comment: @Joey, you bring up a great point. I believe the solution in light of that is `SequenceEquals`.

Comment: This breaks on `sut.DataFields = { "A" }, `expected = { "A", "A" }` and also breaks on `sut.DataFields = { "A" }`, `expected = { "A", "B" }` because `sut.DataFields.Except(expected)` is empty, so `.Any()` returns `false`, so `IsEqual` will be `true`, but `sut.DataFields` and `expected` are *not* equal. `SequenceEquals` will work, but *only* if order matters.

Comment: @Jason, considering it's a unit test, making order matter is going to be pretty straight forward. And may even be more correct because it should concrete the unit test a bit more. I'm thinking that the less wiggle room I have here the better.

Comment: @The Solution: I have no idea what you're talking about. Either order matters or *in your domain* or it doesn't. The correct thing to do is not to force ordering in your unit tests, but handle whatever needs to be correct *for your domain*. If order matters in your domain, handle it with `SequenceEquals`. If it doesn't, you need a more general approach. This isn't about wiggle room, or concreteness in your unit tests. *You need to test for what the specification is in your domain*. The broader point is that you should have been more precise in your question statement here.

Answer (score 1):

### If order is important

Use [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx)

Sample from the above link:

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void SequenceEqualEx1()
{
    Pet pet1 = new Pet { Name = "Turbo", Age = 2 };
    Pet pet2 = new Pet { Name = "Peanut", Age = 8 };

    // Create two lists of pets.
    List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };
    List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };

    bool equal = pets1.SequenceEqual(pets2);

    Console.WriteLine(
        "The lists {0} equal.",
        equal ? "are" : "are not");
}
```

---

### If order is not important

Start by ordering the enumerables and then use Enumerable.SequenceEqual as above.

Comment: Ordering, and then using `SequenceEquals` is `O(n log n)`. We can do [better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17883922/45914), `O(n)` in fact (`n` is the maximum length of the two arrays).

Comment: @Jason n log n < n for n < 10. For n > 10 it's correct that n log n > n, but I didn't even consider such optimization in this case since I'm not sure it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not fully specified. You did *not* define "equality" for arrays.

In particular, does order matter? What about item counts?

If order *does* matters:

```
return first.SequenceEquals(second);
```

If counts do *not* matter:

```
return !first.Except(second).Union(second.Except(first)).Any();
```

If order does *not* matter and counts *do* matter, you need an approach like the following:

```
public bool Compare<T>(T[] first, T[] second) {
    var firstItemCounts = first.GroupBy(x => x)
                               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    var secondItemCounts = second.GroupBy(x => x)
                                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    foreach(var key in firstItemCounts.Keys.Union(secondItemCounts.Keys)) {
        if(!firstItemCounts.ContainsKey(key) ||
               !secondItemCounts.ContainsKey(key)
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        if(firstItemCounts[key] != secondItemCounts[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use class `CollectionAssert`

```
var sut = new PersonValid();
var expected = new string[] { "Id", "FirstName", "LastName" };    
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, sut.DataFields)
```